# Resource Controller Shows White Screen in Laravel 4 Despite Working Routes

Tags: php, rest, laravel-4, controllers

Ok I have a route...

```
Route::resource('sessions', 'SessionsController');
```

Which points to...

```
class SessionsController extends \BaseController {


    public function create()
    {
        return View::make('sessions.create');
    }

...

}
```

/sessions/create gives me a white screen. Nothing. I have no indication it even made it to the controller.

But, if I do this...

```
Route::get('login2', function()
{
    return View::make('sessions.create');
});
```

It works perfectly.

Why is my resource controller broken?

Comment: Look at your laravel.log and also your server log files to see what the error is

Answer (score 0):

So, if you get a white screen, look for a syntax error in your code for that controller. I was missing a :

Many apologies,

Josh